# Executing an onclick event, without clicking.

Tags: javascript, onclick, photo, simulate

I'm using a script called photobooth for JavaScript where the user is supposed to click the camera icon to take a picture, but instead I want it to be code executed. Here is the snippet of code that I believe to be the photobooth take picture event.

```
var L = g("blind");
g("trigger").onclick = function () {
    L.className = "blind", L.style.opacity = 1, setTimeout(function () {
        L.className = "blind anim", L.style.opacity = 0
    }, 50);
    var e = {};
    C.isActive() ? e = C.getData() : f ? e = {
        x: (p - T.videoWidth) / 2,
        y: (d - T.videoHeight) / 2,
        width: T.videoWidth,
        height: T.videoHeight
    } : e = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: p,
        height: d
    };
    var t = y("canvas");
    t.width = e.width, t.height = e.height;
    if (f) t.getContext("2d").drawImage(T, Math.max(0, e.x - (p - T.videoWidth) / 2), Math.max(e.y - (d - T.videoHeight) / 2), e.width, e.height, 0, 0, e.width, e.height);
    else {
        var n = x.getImageData(e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height);
        t.getContext("2d").putImageData(n, 0, 0)
    }
    h.onImage(t.toDataURL())
};
```

I would like to call that event or change it so I can call it, I'm not very good with js so any help would be great!

here is the source: [photobooth js](http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since onclick references a function, you can always call it via

```
document.querySelector(".trigger").onclick()
```

Of course, [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) is just a matter of getting DOM object with desired function, it can be referenced any other way.

Answer (score 9):

is using jquery an option? you can do something like this

```
$("#trigger").click();
```

or if you really want native js you can do something like this

```
document.getElementById("trigger").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Photobooth](http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/#onImage) calls when the user clicks the camera icon:

```
 $('#example').photobooth().on("image",function(ev){});
```

To trigger click on camera icon:

```
$("#example image").click();
```